# Could not find driver "mysql" when setting up sourcebans

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

I'm trying to set up SourceBans on my CS:GO server, but when I tried a `sm_reloadadmins` I got

```
14:46:45 sm_reloadadmins
14:46:45 L 02/09/2013 - 17:46:48: [sourcebans.smx] Database failure: Could not find driver "mysql". See FAQ: http://www.sourcebans.net/node/20
14:46:45 L 02/09/2013 - 17:46:48: [sourcebans.smx] Database failure: Could not find driver "mysql". See FAQ: http://www.sourcebans.net/node/20
14:46:45 L 02/09/2013 - 17:46:48: [sourcebans.smx] Database failure: Could not find driver "mysql". See FAQ: http://www.sourcebans.net/node/20
14:46:45 L 02/09/2013 - 17:46:48: [basecommands.smx] "Console<0><Console><Console>" refreshed the admin cache.
14:46:45 [SM] Admin cache has been refreshed.
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Here's my `databases.cfg`

```
"Databases"
{
    "driver_default"        "mysql"

    // When specifying "host", you may use an IP address, a hostname, or a socket file path

    "default"
    {
        "driver"            "default"
        "host"              "localhost"
        "database"          "sourcemod"
        "user"              "root"
        "pass"              ""
        //"timeout"         "0"
        //"port"            "0"
    }

    "storage-local"
    {
        "driver"            "sqlite"
        "database"          "sourcemod-local"
    }

    "clientprefs"
    {
        "driver"            "sqlite"
        "host"              "localhost"
        "database"          "clientprefs-sqlite"
        "user"              "root"
        "pass"              ""
        //"timeout"         "0"
        //"port"            "0"
    }

    "sourcebans"
    {
        "driver"            "default"
        "host"              "****"
        "database"          "****"
        "user"              "****"
        "pass"              "****"
        //"timeout"         "0"
        "port"          "3306"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have MySQL installed, per [the prerequisites](http://www.sourcebans.net/manual#prereq)? Did you try visiting [the link provided](http://www.sourcebans.net/node/20) to try and solve your issue?

Comment: MySQL is a database management system. You'll need to set it up in order to use Sourcebans, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I have it set up.  To clarify, I already have this set up correctly for my TF2 server.  For some reason I'm running into this issue for my GO server, despite it also being Source and having the same SourceBans configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
"default"
{
    "driver"            "default"
    ...
}
```

so it contains:

`"driver" "mysql"`